# TextView not appearing correctly in Table layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-tablelayout

The textview is not displaying text correctly. The text spans two lines, but the second line of text is only showing the text's upper half, as if the text is cut into 2 halves horizontally, despite using `height = wrap_content`.

**xml code:**

```
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="No. of direct Reportees:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/direct"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:hint="Eg. 12"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>
```

SOLVED:

This behavior is due to baseline alignment. The container has the correct height (it is the max of its two children) but the `Textview` is shifted down to be baseline aligned with the button. This behavior cannot be changed to preserve layouts in existing apps. The correct way to  implement this layout in your case is to add `android:baselineAligned="false"` on the `LinearLayout` tag. This will also get rid of the extra vertical space above the `TextView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is due to baseline alignment. The container has the correct height (it is the max of its two children) but the Textview is shifted down to be baseline aligned with the button. This behavior cannot be changed to preserve layouts in existing apps. The correct way to implement this layout in your case is to add android:baselineAligned="false" on the LinearLayout tag. This will also get rid of the extra vertical space above the TextView.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `TextView` and `EditText` inside the `LinearLayout` to make the weight attribute work:

```
<TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp">
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_row_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="No. of direct Reportees:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/direct"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:hint="Eg. 12"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Getting error: Suspicious size: this will make the view invisible, probably intended for layout_height

Comment: you should not have match_parent inside wrap_content. At the same time I think weight works in table row as well.

Comment: exactly. Height is the problem here

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:text="No. of direct Reportees:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/direct"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:hint="Eg. 12"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</TableRow>
```

Source-

http://www.chess-ix.com/blog/the-use-of-layout_weight-with-android-layouts/

Comment: I need weights...can't delete it

Answer (score 0):

I think height is assigned to the text view before width.

As in because of weight, width is calculated at the time of rendering.

So by the time width is assigned textview's height was set.

I think if text in that textview is going to be static try giving it some hard coded height.